# useActionData type inference issues

Tags: typescript, remix.run

(Note: I assume all of Webstorm's inferred types are simply coming directly from TS, but I'll be clear by specifying the Webstorm commands)

This is my action function:

```
export async function action(args: ActionArgs) {
  const formData = await args.request.formData()
  const parseResult = parseQuantityFormData(formData)

  // response: { result: 'error', error: ErrorType } | ({ result: 'success' } & QuantityFormData)
  const response = await mutateProductInSubscriptionAction(parseResult, args)

  if (response.result === 'error') {
    throw new Error(response.error?.message)
    // return new Response(response.error?.message, { status: 500 })
  }
  return json(response)
}
```

With the code above, the inferred type (by Webstorm: specify type explicitly) of the action data is below. I get this same inferred type whether I call "specify type explicitly" on the action function, or on the `actionData` variable.

```
const actionData: SerializeFrom<
  (args: ActionArgs) => Promise<
    Omit<Response, 'json'> & {
      json(): Promise<{ result: 'success' } & QuantityFormData>
    }
  >
> = useActionData<typeof action>()
```

This allows me to use all my properties and stuff downstream.

Now, if I replace the `throw` with the `return` in the action, Webstorm specifies the *function* type as this, which makes sense

```
async function action(args: ActionArgs): Promise<
  | (Omit<Response, 'json'> & {
      json(): Promise<
        { result: 'success'; error?: null; messages?: null } & QuantityFormData
      >
    })
  | Response
>
```

However, Webstorm specifies the *variable* type differently, as 'any':

```
const actionData: any = useActionData<typeof action>()
```

Furthermore, if I reuse this in a child component, the action data type is inferred there (by hovering on `actionData`, in Webstorm) as `undefined`

```
export function QuantityTestUI({
  modules,
  actionData,
  navigation,
}: {
  modules: ReturnType<typeof useLoaderData<typeof loader>>['modules']
  actionData: ReturnType<typeof useActionData<typeof action>> // undefined!
  navigation: ReturnType<typeof useNavigation>
})
```

It's not `undefined | ...` (I know that `actionData` can be `undefined` before the action is called), it's *only* `undefined`, such that the code below fails with `Property 'result' does not exist on type 'never'.`

```
if (actionData !== undefined && actionData.result === 'success') {
  ...
}
```

The only way I've been able to "solve" this is by writing an explicit type assertion function, that returns `actionData is undefined` but the type of `actionData` in that function has to be constructed very explicitly in a completely unreasonable way

```
type ActionReturn = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof action>>
type ActionJson = ActionReturn['json']
type ActionJsonReturn = ReturnType<ActionJson>
type AwaitedActionJsonReturn = Awaited<ActionJsonReturn>
type TruthyTruthyAwaitedActionJsonReturn = Awaited<
  Extract<ActionJsonReturn, Promise<{ result: 'success' }>>
>

function actionDataValid(
  actionData: AwaitedActionJsonReturn
): actionData is TruthyTruthyAwaitedActionJsonReturn {
  return actionData !== undefined
}
```

I don't want to leave that abomination in my code, so if I want to appropriately return a success `Response` or error `Response` from my `action` function, how do I fix this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix only infers types from `json` and `defer` helpers. You should always `throw` `Response` or `Error`. Remix will handle `redirect` automatically and for the rest, will render nearest `ErrorBoundary`.

My recommendation is:

1. `throw redirect()` on success
2. `return json()` for validation errors
3. `throw new Response()` for client errors like Bad Request
4. `throw new Error()` for server errors

If you must return a success or error response, then use `json` with a discriminated type union.

Comment: `throw new Response` FTW! Thank you!!!